# Failing to catch an exception in SML due to syntax error

Tags: exception, sml, smlnj

I'm trying to add the mechanism of catching an exception after throwing it 
previously in code , but I can't get it to compile :

Here's the code without exception handling - it compiles and works great :

```
fun calc(input : string ) : int = 


    let 
        val outStr = ref "someString"
        val outInt = ref 0

    in 
        (
            outStr := replaceRomanDec(input);       (* replace roman number with decimal *)
            outInt := calcMyRomanExpression(!outStr)    

        );

        (!outInt)

    end;
```

But when I try to put `handle` and `exception`  , here :

```
fun calc(input : string ) : int = 

    exception CalculatorParser

    let 
        val outStr = ref "someString"
        val outInt = ref 0

    in 
        (
            outStr := replaceRomanDec(input);       (* replace roman number with decimal *)
            outInt := calcMyRomanExpression(!outStr);
            handle CalculatorParser =>  -1
        );

        (!outInt)



    end;
```

I get :

```
stdIn:1761.2-1761.28 Error: syntax error: deleting  EXCEPTION ID
-               );
=
=               (!outInt)
=
=
=
=       end;
stdIn:1576.1-1757.2 Error: syntax error: deleting  RPAREN SEMICOLON
```

-

I tried to add/remove a semicolon as was suggested in the error ,but nothing worked .

Any idea what's wrong ?

Kind regards

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you don't use references. Nothing good will come from using them, and you loose the whole point of doing functional programming!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have missunderstod how sequence (expr_1; expr_2; ...; expr_n) of expressions work.

First off, there is no need to first "group" the outStr and outInt in their own sequence, just to use that in another sequence.

Secondly, we don't need parenthesis around a sequence insice the `in ... end` part of a local declaration (let), as there is a derived form (syntactic sugar) to handle that.

Also, there is no need to add parenthesis around a "dereference".

So a simplified version looks like this.

```
fun calc (input : string ) : int =
    let
      val outStr = ref "someString"
      val outInt = ref 0
    in
      outStr := replaceRomanDec input;       (* replace roman number with decimal *)
      outInt := calcMyRomanExpression (!outStr);
      !outInt
    end
```

The grammar for handle is:

> *exp* ::= ... | *exp* **handle** *match* | ...

Thus, the left hand side of handle, must be an expression. You have placed it as the last part of a sequence (exp_1 ; expr_2; expr_3):

```
expr_1   =>   outStr := replaceRomanDec(input);
expr_2   =>   outInt := calcMyRomanExpression(!outStr);
expr_3   =>   handle CalculatorParser => -1
```

From the we see that there is not supplied an expression to the left of handle. Thus you get an syntax error.

Since the result of your exception handling is -1, I assume it is the calcMyRomanExpression that throws the CalculatorParser exception. A solution could thus be:

```
fun calc(input : string ) : int =
    let
      val outStr = ref "someString"
      val outInt = ref 0
    in
      outStr := replaceRomanDec(input);       (* replace roman number with decimal *)
      outInt := (calcMyRomanExpression(!outStr) handle CalculatorParser => ~1);
      !outInt
    end
```

Also remember that minus one is `~1` in SML.

---

As I noted in a comment to your question, you really ought to stop using references when doing functional programming. If you need to use them, then you are almost always doing it wrong.

If you had kept it functional, then the code could have been as simple as:

```
fun calc1 input = (calcMyRomanExpression o replaceRomanDec) input
```

or even simpler

```
val calc2 = calcMyRomanExpression o replaceRomanDec
```

Comment: also, there is no need for parentheses around `input`

Comment: I assume that you mean at the `replaceRomanDec` function. Anyways that what i have updated.